# Django why is a permissions code name different from checking if it has a permission?

Tags: python, django, permissions

When adding a permission to a group I use:

```
managers.permissions.add(
            Permission.objects.get(codename='add_user')
        )
```

Using the codename `add_user`

Now when checking if a user has a particular permission, I use `users.add_user` ie. the `app_name` prepended

```
self.assertTrue(self.user.has_perm('users.add_user'))
```

Why is that. Is it possible to `get` the permission with `users.add_user`.

When I try it I get:

```
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Model names aren't unique. You could have another `User` model in a different app. `Permission.objects.get(codename='add_user')` would fail with a `MultipleObjectsReturned` in that case. It is therefore safer to use sth like:

```
Permission.objects.get(codename='add_user', content_type__app_label='users', content_type__model='user')
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I use this I get `django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Well, check the app_label and model on your permissions content_type, and filter accordingly

Comment: Spot on, my mistake my app label is `users`